# Static PNG image with transparency in IE8

Tags: html, png, transparency

Similar to this question [PNG transparency prоblеm in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251416/png-transparency-problems-in-ie8)

But the answer here was to remove opacity - but I can't remove opacity.  How can it be made to work with opacity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer here was to use a gif - what I was trying to do just didn't seem possible.  Never mind

Answer (score 0):

You could try the workaround linked to in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020690/how-to-make-a-google-maps-semi-transparent-png-tile-layer-work-in-ie8/2075524#2075524). (Haven't tried it myself but seems to work.) I know of no other solution to the problem.