# PNG animation translucency in IE8

Tags: jquery

I've tried many things, but cannot fix this dot fading in with odd edges.
The jQuery is `fadeIn()` here is a [video](http://see.weareinto.com/7ZD8) of the animation.

[image]

---

### Updated

I turned the `div` css backgrounds that I was fading in into actual `img` images and it works great now !

Note: [PNG Transparency Problems in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251416/png-transparency-problems-in-ie8) is also required .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I turned the `div` css backgrounds that I was fading in into actual `img` images and it works great now !

Note: [PNG Transparency Problems in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251416/png-transparency-problems-in-ie8) is also required .