# PNG transparency issue - faded images with black shadows - border in IE

Tags: jquery, shadow, image-rotation

I used image rotator for displaying a few images on the homepage. All image are in the PNG format. The problem is in IE (7, 8) - beside the image there is black shadow... I spent couple of hours with fixing this issue, but still don't know, where is the problem & how to remove it...

Didn't anyone has a similar issue and a tip, how fix that?

Comment: don't use .png images. Open you favorite image editor [ :) ] and mix the images with a slice of the surrounding image and create .jpg images. (The alpha opacity gets messed creating black borders.) 'Export for web and devices' and your images will be smaller than the .png ones you use.

Comment: Read about that issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251416/png-transparency-problems-in-ie8)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with :

```
img.yourimg {
    background: transparent;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00FFFFFF,endColorstr=#00FFFFFF)"; /* IE8 */   
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00FFFFFF,endColorstr=#00FFFFFF);   /* IE6 & 7 */ 
}
```

Or use a PNG8 (it will create a small white border around your images but I think you dont want that.)

Or do like in my comment above.