# Transparent PNG Fix for IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, png, transparent

I have black text over a transparent area and in ie8 it has funky fuzzy black outlines around the text. Is there a way to get rid of this? Thanks

Comment: Please explain how you are currently using PNGs (as you mention them in the title and tags)

Comment: Do you have screecap, and code to what you are doing to the Text?

Comment: Can you provide a link. demo or some code?

Comment: Have you looked into ie9.js? http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/

Comment: @jrod i cannot provide the link as the project im working on is confidential. But basically all it is a png made in photoshop of a card and above the card is black text that is on a transparent layer. The text is fuzzy.

Comment: @KennethAshley Would love to help but without seeing some html and css it would all be guessing.  If you can, recreate the problem in a generic fashion and provide that if confidentiality is an issue.

Comment: Do you have any other filters on the element (or a parent)? From [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=png) "IE7 & 8 do not support PNG alpha transparency, if you put an alpha filter on them or a parent element."

Comment: If this is a 8bit PNG try to save ist as a PNG24. Could solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming by transparent layer, you mean a layer with an opacity setting?

You given this solution a shot?
[PNG transparency prоblеm in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251416/png-transparency-problems-in-ie8)

Go here: http://css3please.com/

and use the .box_rgba rule to generate the opacity, instead of the regular 'filter: alpha(opacity=50);' way.