# PNG's showing Grey Background in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, png, transparency

goo.gl/PMvYn

The PNG's seem to display fine in every browser except IE8 and below. Any ideas why this would be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE8 and below don't support PNG transparency directly.

However, here's a work-around that works in IE7 and IE8:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3999844/141172