# ie8 fadein with transparent png not working

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, png, transparency

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PNG Transparency Problems in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251416/png-transparency-problems-in-ie8)

i have this site:

http://thecodefixer.com/tatmuda/blog/

i am using transperent png as my background where needed and internet explorer loves to mess things up.

i have an effect where you press on a link and then you see the background forst and after you see the "site"....

in chrome and firefox it workes great but ie8 doesnt give me a chance...

this is the code plus a code i added from here in stackoverflow:

```
var i;

for (i in document.images) {
if (document.images[i].src) {
    var imgSrc = document.images[i].src;
    if (imgSrc.substr(imgSrc.length-4) === '.png' || imgSrc.substr(imgSrc.length-4) 
=== '.PNG') {
        document.images[i].style.filter = 

"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(enabled='true',sizingMethod='crop',src='" + imgSrc + "')";
    }
}

}

setTimeout(function () { $("div#main").fadeIn("slow"); }, 4000);

setTimeout(function () { $("div#footer").fadeIn("slow"); }, 4000);
```

someone has a fix for this?

Comment: no this is not the problem, i just want a nice fadeIn

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is a problem with IE and (as far as I know) there isn't a fix for it with transparent or alpha-transparent png's.

The best solution I've found is to use solid-background jpg's when you can.