# Animating transparent background images in IE8 and IE7

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, opacity

I am well aware that there are many articles on this, including this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251416/png-transparency-problems-in-ie8).

However, unless I am mistaken, the solution here is not correct as I am still experiencing this issue even though I have applied all suggested fixes in this article, and many others.

This may be down to a few key differences:

1. I am **animating** the opacity of the div
2. I am using a **`background-image`**, not an `img`

A working example of the problem can be found here:

http://jsfiddle.net/J88gq/11/

Any geniuses out there know of a fix? Or alternatively, is anybody aware of a way I can prevent jQuery animating the `filter:alpha(opacity=x)` of any element, as this would, in turn, fix the issue.

Any help much appreciated :-)

**PLEASE NOTE:** You will not see this error in Internet Explorer 9 Compatibility View, you have to test in either IE8 or IE7