# IE8 Transparent PNG issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, png

I am trying to display a transparent PNG as background image (actually bootstrap image) on my page.

Now I want to display it with less opacity. But it is not displaying correctly (displays with some edges around the image)

I know it can be fixed with adding the background-color attribute.

But is there any other way to fix it. I have tried various Microsoft filter attributes...
like

```
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=10)";
  opacity: 0.1;
```

But does not help.

Comment: `IE7` and `IE8` supports transparent `PNG`. `IE6` and earlier not. And your `filer` works fine In `IE8`.

Comment: Shall we assume that it's displaying correctly in other browsers?

Comment: It works in all except IE8

Comment: possible duplicate of [PNG Transparency Problems in IE8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251416/png-transparency-problems-in-ie8)

Answer (score 3):

Use this code instead. Remember it should be in the same order!

**[LIVE DEMO (WORKS EVEN FOR IE6)](http://jsfiddle.net/4qCAp/2/)**

```
.box:hover
{
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=10)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=10);
    -moz-opacity: 0.1;
    -webkit-opacity: 0.1;
    opacity: 0.1;
}
```