# Still rendering png images background black

Tags: html, css, image, cross-browser, png

I have a img which renders png images. The html structure will look like -

```
<img src="abc.png" />
```

It all works well in all browsers except IE8 where the still rendering images is having a black background. In all the other browsers it is transparent (means the background of its parent is seen)

[image]

What is the issue? Is it fixable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the below to your CSS, where you may want to change `img` to a more precise selector for your image, see [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251416/png-transparency-problems-in-ie8) for further information which may be of help to you, I would also recommend you have a look at [this article](http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/ie-transparency-problems/).

```
img {
    background: transparent;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00FFFFFF,endColorstr=#00FFFFFF)"; /* IE8 */   
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00FFFFFF,endColorstr=#00FFFFFF);   /* IE6 & 7 */      
    zoom: 1;    
}
```

Comment: In my project there are options where user can zoom the image to 50%, 100%, 150% etc. Can I remove `zoom:1`?

Comment: You're probably OK to remove `zoom`, you may need to look at the linked articles and find the correct solution to work for your specific situation however- its hard to be more precise without access to code.